# Windows phone 7 sharing API?

Tags: windows-phone-7, flickr, sharing, evernote

I noticed the other day that when I took a photo on Windows Phone 7.5 I got the option to share it to lots of places, including Evernote and Flickr.
As far as I know these are not standard sharing destinations and have probably been added as sharing options by their respective Apps after I downloaded them.

I have found the API to share a link to some of these services.

What I can't seem to find any info on is how I can share photos and other stuff to ALL of the services that seem to be available to the photo app.

I could do it by using the Evernote/Flickr/etc.. APIs myself, but this would require another OAuth signin for the user for each service, something that would not be required if I could leverage the system sharing options.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to do this?

Thanks,
Andi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, as far as I know.

Apps can share to the targets you know - SMS, Email, Social/Link.

The built in photo app, specifically, is extendible in such a way that you can register your app to allow photos to be shared to it.

So, in other words, the only options you have (w/o coding them yourself) are:

Your App -> Email, SMS, Social

Photo -> Your app

Comment: That's a shame, guess it's time to implement OAuth again. :)
Thanks for the response.